# Using fractional in type definition for function to do math computations-getting errors

Tags: haskell, numerical-methods

So i wrote a simple program in haskell to approximate the second derivative of a one variable function with haskell

```
centerDifferenceSecondDerivative :: (Fractional a)=>(a->a)->a->a->a
centerDifferenceSecondDerivative f a h = ((f (a+h)) -2*(f a) + (f (a-h)))/(h^2)
```

Im pretty sure the issue is a type issue due to the fact that i get the weird results below.

```
*Main> centerDifference (\x->(x)) 1 0.000001
    0.9999999999732445
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(0)) 1 0.000001
    0.0
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(4*x^2)) 1 0.000001
    8.000000000008
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(4*x^2)) 3 0.000001
    24.00000000335467
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(cos x)) 0 0.000001
    0.0
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(sin x)) 0 0.000001
    0.9999999999998334
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(sin x)) 0 0.00000000001
    1.0
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(x^3)) 0 0.00000000001
    9.999999999999999e-23
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(x^3)) 1 0.00000000001
    3.000000248221113
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(x^3)) 2 0.00000000001
    12.000000992884452
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(x^3)) 3 0.00000000001
    26.999913416148047
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(x^3)) 4 0.00000000001
    48.00000397153781
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(x^3)) 5 0.00000000001
    74.99991738768585
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(x)) 5 0.00000000001
    1.000000082740371
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(x)) 20 0.00000000001
    1.000088900582341
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(x)) 100 0.00000000001
    1.000444171950221
    *Main> centerDifference (\x->(x)) 100 0.1
    0.9999999999999432
```

If someone could give me insight on this type stuff that be great, ive just always used fractional for math but it seems there are issues with that.

Comment: What is `centerDifference`? When I try your first example with `centerDifferenceSecondDerivative` I get a different result as well: `-1.1102230246251565e-4`. Be sure to turn on `-Wall` so you see how numeric types are being defaulted.

Comment: What is it that you consider weird about these results?

Comment: Note than for small h you get massive cancellation errors.

Comment: BTW, the correct way to do differentiation in Haskell is not numeric but ["automatic"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad). Wait... didn't I tell you already? — On another note: parens around the result of a lambda aren't needed, you can write `centerDifference (\x -> 4*x^2) 1 0.000001`.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys i found my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing the truncation error of the floating point arithmetic -- nothing to do with types.

I assume you defined centerDifference as
centerDifference f a h = ((f (a+h)) - (f (a-h)))/2h

It is actually tricky to compute derivatives accurately with finite difference formula. Extremely small values of h are not good, because they introduce large quantization errors. Too large a value for h and the formula won't be close enough to the limiting value. You can't win. With optimal choice of h the results will typically be accurate to about 2/3 machine prescision.

First you should choose a value for h which has many trailing 0s in its binary floating point -- try 2^-17. The optimal value depends on the behavior of the function at the point a. A nice discussion on numerical differentiation can be found in Numerical Recipes in C page 186: google it and you will find a pdf of the book. It discusses the phenomena in depth.

Here is a shot at explaining why the error in the first result is larger than you were expecting (about 3*10^-11 when you were probably thought you would get an error closer to the machine precision ~10^-16).

A double floating point number can represent any of 2^52 numbers between 0.5 <= x < 1.0. Since the interval is of length 1/2 these numbers are 2^-53 apart. There are 2^52 floating point numbers between 1.0 <= x < 2.0. Since this interval has length 1 those numbers are 2^52 apart. Roughly speaking the result of computing 1-h is represented more accurately than the result of computing 1+h. Consequently (the results of computing) 1-h and 1+h are not symmetric around 1. Subtracting (1+h)-(1-h) yields an error ~2^-53. Then you divide this by 2*10^-6 which scales the error up to about 5*10^-11 which is approximately the error in the result.

Comment: Thank you, this helped quite a bit.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @John, and to the [haskell] tag in particular. What a great first post.